# how to avoid scriplets in the case we need a list only in the view

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl, freemarker

I am developing a java webapp.  In the view it would be nice if I could create a list/sequence that only the view knows about.

But JSTL cannot (as I understand it) cannot create list, but can only be given a list.  But often we need a list dynamically created that only the jsp knows about (which the control and model should know nothing about).  Here is a simple mock example, in which I use a scriplet to create a list that would later be looped by JSTL.

Is the following bad practice?  How else would one go about this, as often we need lists that are only part of the view and not the model or control.  I am used to Freemarker, and regularly create sequences that are only for the view, how else to do this in JSTL without using a scriplet, any ideas?  I know scriplets should be avoided, but what do people think about this situation (as things like this are included with FreeMarker?

```
<%  // this code could go at the top or in an imported header
    ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
    colors.add("red");
    colors.add("green");
    colors.add("blue");
    colors.add("orange");
    request.setAttribute("colors", colors);
%>

<c:forEach items="${colors}" var="color">   
    color= ${color} </br>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSTL doesn't have any tool to declare a list, but you can use [`fn:split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/split.fn.html) to create an array from a String:

```
<c:set var="colors" value="${fn:split('red,green,blue,orange', ',')}"  />
```

However, in my point of view, it is not a very good practice, as it is not very readable, and I think that the maintenance would be easier if the list was defined in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Scriplets indeed should be avoided.
This problem can be solved by involving a little bit MVC structure/idea
You can use a servlet to create the list and then save the list to the request object.
In your servlet:

```
ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
colors.add("red");
colors.add("green");
colors.add("blue");
colors.add("orange");

request.setAttribute("colors", colors);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("yourPage.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
return;
```

in "yourpage.jsp", you can use EL and jstl to display the list like you did.
please note that you still need to do some research on how to create servlet, but it is pretty easy to learn.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I know how to create a servlet and I know how to pass request objects to a jsp (perhaps I should have made that more clear in the question).  We are currently using servlets as the control component of MVC.  It seems silly to have servlets (which in our case are primarily the control of MVC) build lists that only the view should know about (common need).  That practice seems worse than throwing in a few scriplets on the rare occasion, because then the servlet would need to have knowledge of what kind of UI lists might be necessary.

Comment: the reason I said that the solution seems "worse" is that it seems to violate MVC principles more greatly.   the whole idea of MVC is to separate view from controller and model. This principle seems to be violated if the routing servlet needs to know what kinds of lists to make for the UI.  I am here talking about lists that pertain to the UI not lists that are data driven (those clearly should be passed by the servlet and not obtained or built inside the jsp).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In your code, the values of the color is sort of hard coded in jsp. What if the values are dynamically changing - in database or xml file? You might not want to go back to your jsp and change it manually. Instead, you can write code in your servlet to grab the dynamically changing data and send the data to your view. I think it follows the principle of MVC structure. It is easy to maintain. It is hard for me to point out all the possible reasons and advantage of using servlet and the coding details. But I hope it gives you some perspectives.

Comment: I think my responses are kind of off topic. In general, I think the code you originally posted is not a very good practice.

Comment: thanks Alex, I do agree that my code posted is not good practice, but I also think that building UI lists in the servlet is also not good practice.  IMHO, I think FreeMarker is much better for view than JSTL, so I will just stick to my stengths on my project and not try to do with JSTL things that it was not meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answers I recieved, but I am going to go a head and answer my own question (though I am open to more feedback).

It appears that JSTL does provide a basic way of creating lists through strings. The following will create a comma separated list (of sorts) and store it in the page scope.

```
<c:set var="colors" scope="page" value="red,green,blue,orange"/>
```

This list can then be looped over using the following

```
<c:forEach var="color" items="${colors}">
    <LI>${color} <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

This does not require use of the split function, and is handled automatically in the loop. While ',' is the default delim.  I think this is pretty clean and will handle most cases for the UI.

I do not like the idea of building UI related lists int servlet, as that seems to violate MVC more than putting in a simple scriplet, but the above seems to work, and the split function should work well also if needed.